# Declaration of MYPDF::Header() should be compatible with TCPDF::Header()

Tags: php, tcpdf

Hello to all!

I'm trying to override the *Header* method passing the variable `$ecm` but I get this message:

```
    "Declaration of MYPDF::Header() should be compatible with TCPDF::Header()"
```

What do you think?
I can get around the obstacle? 
Thanks.

```
  <code>  
    $pdf = new MYPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
    $ecm="1241231.jpg";
    $pdf->Header($ecm);
    $pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I'); //To force download    }


    // Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
    class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
        //Page header
        public function Header($ecm) {
          ....

        }
    }
</code>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pdf = new MYPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
$ecm="1241231.jpg";

$pdf->setECM($ecm);
$pdf->Header();

$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I'); //To force download    }


// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public $ecm;
    public function setECM($ecm)
    {
        $this->ecm = $ecm;
    }

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        $ecm = $this->ecm;
      ....

    }
}
```

Comment: I really want to kiss you! You saved my life!